# How can I auto-add an index property to an array of PHP objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, indexing

I'm building an array of objects, like this:

```
$my_array[] = (object) array(
    'url' => 'http://someurl.com',
    'created' => '06/26/2011',
    'some_value' => true,
);


$my_array[] = (object) array(
    'url' => 'http://someurl2.com',
    'created' => '07/26/2011',
    'some_value' => false,
);


$my_array[] = (object) array(
    'url' => 'http://someurl3.com',
    'created' => '08/26/2011',
    'some_value' => true,
);
```

Now, I know i'm generating an index value for the array key.  But I'd also like to have an index value as a property inside the object, i.e. index => 1, 2 or 3 in this case.  Except I  need it to be automatic.

Is there something that would work like this?  Where $key is automatically added?

```
$my_array[] = (object) array(
            'index' => $key,
    'url' => 'http://someurl3.com',
    'created' => '08/26/2011',
    'some_value' => true,
);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can create a class that implements the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), then point to the appropriate property (assigning it as the key).

Comment: that is a great idea. :) thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to add the array key to the element, this would be available to you when you step through the loop:

```
foreach ($my_array as $key => $element) 
{
    var_dump($element['url']);
    var_dump($key);
}
```

And just a question, are you typecasting an array as an object?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the foreach $key syntax, that's good to remember.  what does it mean to typecase an array as an object?

Comment: You are doing the `$my_array = (object) array();` syntax... the `(object) or (int) or (float)` constructs will typecast the value into that datatype.

Answer (score 0):

try use key function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

`'index' => key( this ),`

not sure it work, but I would go that way